# Como receber valores de JSON e logo após inseri-los no banco de dados em PHP

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldades em obter os valores de JSON que consulto do meu estoque, após consultá-lo e preencher meus inputs eu preenchi mais alguns campos manualmente e logo após o cadastro todo este conjunto em outro banco. O problema está quando vou cadastrar estes inputs que preenche com JSON, pois eles aparentam estar vazios em PHP, porém na visualização do input está OK.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='codProduto[]']").blur(function(){
     var nomeProduto = $("input[name='nomeProduto[]']");
     var qtProduto = $("input[name='qtProduto[]']");
     var valorProduto = $("input[name='valorProduto[]']");

     $( nomeProduto ).val('Carregando...');
     $( qtProduto ).val('Carregando...');
     $( valorProduto ).val('Carregando...');

         $.getJSON(
             'function.php',
             { codProduto: $( this ).val() },
             function( json ) 
             {
                  $( nomeProduto ).val( json.nomeProduto );
                  $( qtProduto ).val("1");
                  $( valorProduto ).val( json.valorProduto);
             }


         );
 });
 });
```

Trecho com inputs

```
     <form id="form1" name"form1" method"post" action"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="produtos">
          <p class="campoProduto">
          <label>Cód Produto: <input type="text" name="codProduto[]" id="codProduto[]" size="5"/></label>
          <label>Produto: <input name="nomeProduto[]" type="text" size="10" value="" /></label> 
          <label>Qt.:  <input type="number" min="1" max="999" size="1" name="qtProduto[]" id="qtProduto[]" onblur="calcValor()" /></label>
          <label>Valor R$: <input type="text" name="valorProduto[]" id="valorProduto[]" size="6" onkeypress="mascara(this,float)"/></label>
          <a href="#" class="removerProduto">Remover Produto</a> 
               </p>
             </div>
             <p>
              <a href="#" class="adicionarProduto">Adicionar Produto</a>
            </p>
            <br>
          <label>Data da Compra <input name="datacompra" type="text" id="datacompra" size="6" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y')?>" onKeyUp="javascript:somente_numero(this);" onkeypress="formatar_mascara(this,'##/##/####')"/></label>
   <label>Desconto (%)<span style="display:none" id="sp_vdesconto"></span><input type="hidden"  name="vdesconto" id="vdesconto" />:<input type="text" name="desconto" size="6" value="0"id="desconto" onblur="calcValor()" /></label>   
   <label>Entrada R$<span style="display:none" id="sp_vdentrada"></span><input type="hidden" size="6" name="vdentrada" id="vdentrada" />:<input type="text" name="entrada" size="6" value="0"id="entrada" onblur="calcValor()" /></label> 
   <label>Pacelas:  <input type="number" min="1" max="6" size="1" value="1" name="parcelas" maxlength="2" size="2" id="parcelas"/></label>  
   <label>Valor Total: <input type="text" name="total" size="6" id="total" /></label> 
               <input type="reset">
             <input type="hidden" name="cadastra" value="add" />
             <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="  Cadastrar  " />  
       </form>
```

e o momento da inserção no banco de dados:

```
<?php   if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
  $datacompra = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET['datacompra'])));
  $nomeProduto = $_GET['nomeProduto[]'];
  $qtProduto = $_GET['qtProduto[]'];
  $valorProduto = $_GET['valorProduto[]'];
  $pagamento = "CREDIARIO";
  $ficha = $_GET['cadastro'];
        $cadastra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_cadcontratos (Ficha, NumContrato,DataContrato, QuantParcelas, ValorContrato, Entrada, Saldo, DescricaoProduto, QuantProdutos, FormaPagamento) 
                            VALUES ('$ficha', '$datacompra', ('$_GET[parcelas]'), '$valorProduto', ('$_GET[entrada]'), ('$_GET[total]'),
                            UPPER('$nomeProduto'), ('$qtProduto'), '$pagamento')");
    if($cadastra == '1') {
        echo "Venda CREDIARIO realizada com sucesso !";
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao realizar a venda CREDIARIO, tente novamente !";
}
}
?>
```

Segue trecho do arquivo .js que utilizo para adicionar e remover inputs para novos produtos:

```
$(function () {
    function removeProduto() {
        $(".removerProduto").unbind("click");
        $(".removerProduto").bind("click", function () {
            i=0;
            $(".produtos p.campoProduto").each(function () {
                i++;
            });
            if (i>1) {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            }
        });
    }
    removeProduto();
    $(".adicionarProduto").click(function () {
        novoCampo = $(".produtos p.campoProduto:first").clone();
        novoCampo.find("input").val("");
        novoCampo.insertAfter(".produtos p.campoProduto:last");
        removeProduto();
    });
});
```

O erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: No php você precisa colocar colchete no nome da chave, deve fazer um `foreach` para pegar todos o valores ex: `foreach($_GET['nomeProduto'] as $item){....}` lembre de verificar se o $_GET não é vazio.

Comment: Certo, o problema eu resolvo tirando os colquetes e usando para buscar o valor "filter_input", até ai ok, mas preciso usar um certo array pois como visto no código acima vou adicionar mais produtos em tempo e após inseri-los no banco também, ou seja terei um array de produtos que depois precisarei tirar de estoque ou acrescentar... tens alguma ideia de como posso fazer esse controle com JSON e após usar no PHP/BD? no aguardo e obrigado mesmo!

acima inseri o trecho que adicione e removo novos inputs referente a cada produto.

Answer (score 1):

Ao tentar perceber o seu trecho de código, observo que o erro que tem, deve-se ao formulário `HTML` utilizar o método `POST` e o depois quer obter essas variáveis em `$_GET` o que não pode ser terá de ser em `$_POST`.

Tenho que dizer que acho o seu código meio confuso, mas especialmente na ligação que faz do php no html e Jquery de qualquer forma para recolher a informação do form no JQUERY faça desta forma:

```
var fld = JSON.stringify(array_de_campos);
```

que depois coloca como parametro do seu request AJAX e finalmente no PHP:

```
$array_de_campos = json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, $string_em_transito), true);
```

lembro que deve filtrar todo o input... pelo que coloco um exemplo explicativo para o tema do JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Você está recebendo os dados com `$_GET`, mas seu formulário está definido como `method"post"` (apesar de estar errado, então não sei se conta). Receba os dados com `$_POST` e arrume o atributo `method="POST"`.

Os campos com `[]` (chaves no final do nome) é interpretado como *array*, então receba-os da seguinte forma:

```
$nomeProduto = $_POST['nomeProduto'][0];
```

Você também pode remover as `[]` (chaves) caso haja apenas um elemento com este nome, ou caso haja vários, pode interpretar como um *array* normal.